# How to display all the dates when plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, plot, time-series

I have a timeseries dataset of a month. I am plotting it using matplotlib in python however I am not able to display all the dates of a month on the x-axis. I want the x-axis to show full dates. The dataset looks something like this:

```
Date and Time Temperature
7/1/2022 0:00  25.4
7/1/2022 0:15  23.2
7/1/2022 0:30  22.5
7/1/2022 0:45  23
7/1/2022 1:00  22.3
7/1/2022 1:15  22
```

And here is my code for plotting the data:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))

df_0.plot(kind='line', x='Date and Time', y='Temperature', ax=ax, label='Week 1')

df_1.plot(kind='line', x='Date and Time', y='Temperature', ax=ax, label='Week 2')

df_2.plot(kind='line', x='Date and Time', y='Temperature', ax=ax, label='Week 3')

df_3.plot(kind='line', x='Date and Time', y='Temperature', ax=ax, label='Week 4')

df_4.plot(kind='line', x='Date and Time', y='Temperature', ax=ax, label='Week 5')

plt.xlabel('Date and Time of the month - July')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m.%d.%Y"))

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

The data I has was in one single dataframe. I divided into different dataframes in order plot it on a weekly basis. Here is the output:
[image]

I have tried using ax.axis method, DateFormatter and DayLocator however none of these is having any effect on the graph. I want the axis to show full dates like 22-07-2022 etc. And I can confirm that the Date and Time column is in datetime format.

Comment: It works if you just use `pyplot.plt` so it is related with how `pandas` handles the plot, as @FObersteiner says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date/time column to datetime data type, then use `x_compat = True` to enforce Python datetime compatibility, which in turn allows to use mdates formatter correctly.

Given

```
df
   Date and Time  Temperature
0  7/1/2022 0:00         25.4
1  7/1/2022 0:15         23.2
2  7/1/2022 0:30         22.5
3  7/1/2022 0:45         23.0
4  7/1/2022 1:00         22.3
5  7/1/2022 1:15         22.0
```

that can look like

```py
df['Date and Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date and Time'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 10))

df.plot(kind='line', x='Date and Time', y='Temperature', ax=ax, label='Week 1',
        x_compat=True)

plt.xlabel('Date and Time of the month - July')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m.%d.%Y"))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))

plt.show()
```

[image]